# Ways to upload data to gcloud from teradata

Tags: google-compute-engine, teradata, gcloud, gsutil

Does anyone know a better transfer method that can be set up ?
So far I have tried these two 2 step methods

---

1. Use Teradata SQL Assistant to export data to my machine
   Upload on GCP webpage
2. Use shell scripting and BTEQ to export data to linux server
   Upload from server using gsutil

---

Improvement on step 2 above or ideally a single step  process?